# Creating Django Models Without Rounding off Decimal Fields

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

For now, when I save an amount like 5400.5789, it is being saved as 5400.58. However, I want it to be saved as 5400.57 only. I don't want to round off the decimal places. How can I achieve that?

```
class PerTransaction(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=10,decimal_places=2, verbose_name = "Transaction Amount")
```

Database: PostgreSQL

Comment: Why don't you truncate manually before assigning the value?

Comment: you may need to handle it manually before saving the value

Comment: use Truncator class from Django django.utils.text module

Comment: example is mentioned in code

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import Truncator
class PerTransaction(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name="Transaction Amount")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        truncated_amount = Truncator(self.amount).truncate_decimal(2)
        self.amount = truncated_amount
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Do I need to perform migrations for def save()?

Comment: no save method in Django model is part of the model logic and doesnot affect the database schema